# AngularJS, connecting to a database

Tags: angularjs, database, intellij-idea

I made a simple web page in angular JS with a list of phones, with a search query and sort by. 
The information is stored in a .component.js file.
I have a .template.html file and an index.html file as well as other AngularJS files.

I have connected a database to my project, as instead of storing the data into a .component.js file, I want to display it through the database.

How do I display information from a database via Angular? (I'm using IntelliJ).

this is my .component.js file: ...

```
angular.
  module('phoneList').
   component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: function PhoneListController() {
  this.phones = [
    {
      name: 'Iphone 6S',
      rating: 3,
      maker: 'Apple'
    }, { 
...
}
];
this.orderProp = 'rating';
}):
```

Do I have to completely change the whole layout of my project?

I connected the database through MySQL and the database is phoneList, with one table: phones and columns Phone Name, Rating, Maker

Comment: Which database you are using and I think you want a hit on every sorting calls?

Comment: You write a backend, exposing RESTful services over HTTP, that get data out of your database, transform them to JSON, and send them back as a response. You can't connect your angular app directly to your database.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: That's a much too broad question. There are entire books and frameworks, in all languages, covering this topic.